# How to deal with browser freezing because of nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree

I created a nested tree which may have 1 - 5000 items, I am able to make it work but it freezes my browser\loading spinner for few seconds just before showing the tree.

***How can I make it smooth so browser would never freeze ?***

***How can I know when angularjs finished creating or rendering or computing (not sure right word) whole list so that I could remove loading spinner then, as you can see scope.$last won't work as we have nested ng-repeat and same for scope.$parent.$last***

Here is plunker I created but with demo data -

http://plnkr.co/edit/GSZEpHjt5YVxqpg386k5?p=preview

Example dataset - http://pastebin.com/YggqE2MK

It's not too bad in this example but at points my browser freezes for more then 10 seconds for around 4000 items in my OWN setup with all other components.

**What I already considered**

- used bindonce.js library but without much success
- used "::" single binding without much success again
- only load first level then render next level when user expands a category but my tree can be very random, maybe I only have 1 single root node with 100s child nodes
- pagination is not ideal for scenario

**HTML**

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item">
    <div ng-init="category.expanded=true">
      <div ng-class="{'selected': category.ID==selectedCategoryID}">
        <div class="icon icon16" ng-if="category.Children.length>0" ng-click="$parent.category.expanded=!$parent.category.expanded" ng-class="$parent.category.expanded?'col':'exp'"></div>
        <div class="icon icon-category" ng-class="'icon-category-'+category.TypeType" ng-style="{'border-color':category.Colour}" ng-attr-title="{{category.Status?Res['wpOPT_Status'+category.Status]:''}}"></div>
        <a ng-href="#id={{category.ID}}" ng-class="{'pending-text': category.PendingChange}">{{category.Name}}</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="emlist" ng-show="category.expanded">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.Children | orderBy:'Name'" ng-include="'tree_item'" ng-class="{'selected': category.ID==selectedCategoryID}" e2-tree-item is-selected="category.ID==selectedCategoryID">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div id="CategoryListContainer" class="dragmenu-container initial-el-height">
    <div class="spinner" data-ng-show="status=='loading'"></div>
    <ul id="CategoryList" class="dragmenu-list ng-cloak" ng-show="status=='loaded'">
      <li ng-repeat="category in tree | orderBy:'Name'" ng-include="'tree_item'" e2-tree-item is-selected="category.ID==selectedCategoryID"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('recursionDemo', []);

app.controller("TreeController", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.status = "loading";

  $timeout(function() {
        var result = {
      "GetCategoryTreeResult": [{ // too big data set so I pasted it here http://pastebin.com/YggqE2MK }];
    $scope.tree = result.GetCategoryTreeResult;

    $scope.status = "loaded";
  }, 3000);
});

app.directive('e2TreeItem', function($timeout) {
  function link(scope, element, ngModel) {
    scope.$watch('isSelected', function(oldVal, newVal) {
      if (scope.isSelected === true) {
        element.parentsUntil('#CategoryListContainer', 'li').each(function(index, item) {
          angular.element(item).scope().category.expanded = true;
        });
      }
    });

    // not working
    //if (scope.$parent.$last) {
    //  console.log("last has been caught");
    //  var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=recursionDemo]');
    //  angular.element(appElement).scope().status = "loaded";
    //}
  }
  return {
    link: link,
    scope: {
      isSelected: '=?'
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: You can use one way binding for ng-repeat or lazy loading of ng-repeat that may help you.

Comment: using `track by` can help immensely with performance

Comment: you should use virtual/infinite scroll - either existing one or develope your own. Nothing else will really help.

Comment: I was going to recommend using a `Web Worker` to let angular do it's thing without blocking the main UI thread.  However, since this version of angular is so coupled to the DOM, it's not trivial.  This becomes trivial with Angular2+ or React.

Comment: For what it's worth, this uses a `Web Worker` to sort by name (so Angular doesn't have to do it), but it does not stop the blocking of the main UI thread when reassigning to `$scope`. If someone can take the `Web Worker` approach further, I'd love to see it.  http://plnkr.co/edit/3UPXT5Hr98axn4XFVb5d?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

DEMO:http://plnkr.co/edit/bHMIU8Mx5grht9nod1CW?p=preview

You can load your data smoothly by changing the L10901 of app.js as below. But you should notice that if you still want to order it by name, and want it steady, you should just sort the source data, but not sort in angular with "order by". (Do you want some code to sort the source data?)

```
    function getDataGradually(data, childKey, gap, count, updateCb, finishCb) {
        const lastPositon = [];
        const linearData = [];
        const ret = [];


        function getLinearData(arr, position) {
            arr.forEach(function (obj, index) {
                const pos = position.concat([index]);
                if (obj[childKey] && obj[childKey].length) {
                    var children = obj[childKey];
                    obj[childKey] = [];
                    linearData.push({
                        obj,
                        pos
                    });
                    getLinearData(children, pos);
                } else {
                    linearData.push({
                        obj,
                        pos
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        getLinearData(data, []);

        function insertData({
            obj,
            pos
        }) {

            let target = ret;
            pos.forEach(function (i, index) {


                if (index === pos.length - 1) {
                    target[i] = obj;

                } else {
                    target = target[i][childKey];
                }
            });

        }
        let handled = 0;

        function doInsert() {
            let start = handled;
            let end;
            if (handled + count > linearData.length) {
                end = linearData.length;
            } else {
                end = handled + count;
            }
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
                insertData(linearData[i]);
            }
            handled += count;
            if (handled < linearData.length) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    doInsert();
                    updateCb && updateCb();
                }, gap);
            } else {
                finishCb && finishCb();
            }
        }
        doInsert();



        return ret;
    }

    $scope.tree = getDataGradually(result.GetCategoryTreeResult, "Children", 0, 30, function () {
      $scope.$digest();
    }, function () {
      //finished 
    });
    //$scope.tree = result.GetCategoryTreeResult;
    $scope.status = "loaded";
  }, 3000);
```

**Old answer:**

You can get the rendering time by using $timeout. Try to change the L10901 of app.js as below.

```
        $scope.tree = result.GetCategoryTreeResult;
        console.time("A")
        $timeout(function(){
          console.timeEnd("A");
        });
        $scope.status = "loaded";
      }, 3000);
```

BTW, I got "1931.881ms" on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is:

In Controller :

```
// Consider results to be my main array, which contains 5000 items
var results = [{ ... }, { ... }, ..., ..., { ... }];

$scope.bindResults = results.slice(0, 5);

// Here you can start loading
$scope.status = "loading";

// Inject $interval in controller
var interval = $interval(function() {
    $scope.bindResults = results.slice(0, $scope.bindResults.length + 5);

    if($scope.bindResults.length >= results.length) {
         $interval.cancel(interval);

        // Here you can end loading
        $scope.status = "loading";
    }
}, 10);
```

In HTML :

```
<span ng-repeat="x in bindResults"></span>
```

This won't hang up the browser and will keep populating data every 10 ms, you can increase that number as required.

Comment: Your function is incorrect.  Your $scope.bindResults will always be the same, and your interval will be canceled in the first iteration.

The principle seems sound, but the implementation is wrong. Check your slice and if conditions

Comment: I want to implement something similar but I have nested ng-repeats and nested dataset so this will be very difficult to apply

Comment: @Ladmerc - yes, you are right, had missed the `+ 5`, have updated the answer and also reversed if condition

Comment: @Mathematics - is your main dataset big or nested datasets' also big, I have my main dataset very big, so this worked

Comment: @Aks1357 thanks for your answer, did you get a chance to look at plunker I added, it has a example

Comment: if you don't want to consider pagination, this seems to be a nice fit, at least in the idea. I haven't checked if it works properly.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- as explained in comments above, this trick or pagination won't going to work with dynamic & nested trees

Answer (score 0):

From my experience:

- move filter logic to JS (do not order in HTML, but before)
- try track by in usage with ng-repeat
- ng-include with ng-repeat has bad performance - read this [Using ng-repeat with ng-include](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2738-using-ngrepeat-with-nginclude-hurts-performance-in-angularjs.htm) or this [Alternative for ng-include in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515882/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-ng-include-on-a-multidimensional-array)

Also this is old, but good article on angularjs performance with ng-repeat [Optimizing AngularJS: 1200ms to 35ms](http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/)